# How to return georgian string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation, georgian

I have a query below:

```
case 
   when 1 = (select Loc_ID from tbl_Web_User where Phone = '123456789') 
      then 'Reached Quota' 
      else 'მიღწეული კვოტა' 
end
```

When I returned georgian characters, it returns `??????????` like this.
How can I show georgian string correctly?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YEAR(DateEntered) BETWEEN  1714 AND 1830`

Comment: what do you mean? @MartinSmith

Comment: You wanted a [Georgian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_era) string?

Comment: Yes @MartinSmith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to specify that you need **Unicode** string literals - you do that by prefixing the string with a `N` - like this:

```
case 
   when 1 = (select Loc_ID from tbl_Web_User where Phone = '123456789') 
      then N'Reached Quota' 
      else N'მიღწეული კვოტა' 
end
```

Comment: This is what i want thank you @marc_s it work for me